# Overloading istream operator to show fractions in multi line project

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello Stackoverflow this is indeed my first post ever on this forum. I needed some guidance on my c++ program, I am in a situation where I do not know where to start to make my normal and mixed fractions display from a file. Here is what I have so far for the header and implementation file. ***The Main Focus is The iStream Function in Fraction.cpp to be able to display mixed and normal fractions from a file.*** Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my Fraction.cpp code

```
/* USED FOR FUNCTIONS */
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <cassert>
#include "fraction.h"
using namespace std;

namespace cs10b_fraction
{


ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Fraction printMe)
{

    if (printMe.denom == 1)
    {
        out << printMe.num << endl;
    }

    else if (printMe.num == 0)
    {
        out << printMe.num << endl;
    }

    else if(printMe.denom == -1)
        out << printMe.num / printMe.denom << endl;

    else if(printMe.num < printMe.denom && printMe.num != 0)
        out << printMe.num << "/" << printMe.denom << endl;

    else if(abs(printMe.num) > abs(printMe.denom))
        out << printMe.num / printMe.denom << "+" << (printMe.num % printMe.denom) << "/" << printMe.denom << endl;



   /* else if (abs(printMe.num) > abs(printMe.denom))
        out << printMe.num / printMe.denom << endl;

    else if (abs(printMe.num) > abs(printMe.denom))
        out << printMe.num / printMe.denom << "+" << (printMe.num % printMe.denom) << "/" << printMe.denom << endl; */

    return out;
}

istream& operator >> (std::istream &in, Fraction readMe)
{
   int temp;
   in >> temp;



    if (in.peek() == '+')
    {

    }

    else if (in.peek() == '/')
    {

    }

    else
    {

    }

    return in;

}

}
```

Here is my Fraction.h code

```
/*USED FOR CLASS WITH FUNCTIONS ETC */
#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

namespace cs10b_fraction
{
class Fraction
{
public:
    Fraction(int n = 0, int d = 1)
    {
        num = n;
        denom = d;
        assert(denom != 0);
        Simplify();
    }

friend ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Fraction printMe);
friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &in, Fraction readMe);

private:
    int num;
    int denom;

    void Simplify();
};
}

#endif
```

Comment: The fractions to be shown should be :
-1/3
3/6
3072/4096
-4/5
12/2
5
-8
21/15
-50/3
1+1/4
1+5/5
-4+3/12
-10+10/12

Comment: Please be more specific than "I am a bit in a pickle" and remove all the code that is not relevant to your issue. (Also, you are "in a bit of a pickle".)

Comment: I think all of the code is necessary for the problem since its a multi file project, i should have said "My main issue is having the istream function from the fraction.cpp work to display mixed and normal fractions in my client.cpp"

Comment: The massive `main`, your output operator, and your simplification  are not relevant to the problem of implementing the input operator.

Comment: I see what you mean, edited and made it a bit more concise

Answer (score 0):

One important hint: `operator<<` and `operator>>` should take second argument by reference, otherwise they are passed by value and you (1) create unnecessary overhead for copying object when passing it for output operator, and (2) make impossible to get value you've read out of input operator. The rest - algorithm of reading and printing out values - is something that you have to figure out on your own - sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a site where people do other's homeworks.